# How can I change mainClassName in build.gradle during runtime?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, command-line-arguments

I'm using gradle for a multiplayer game I'm implementing in java.

In the project I have two classes named Server and Client and I want to be able to choose which one to run during runtime. Is there any way I can do this by giving arguments to gradle tasks in command line? For example, I want to use somthing like
`./gradlew run -server` to run Server.java and`./gradlew run -client` to run Client.java.

Right now I have this in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}


application {
    mainClassName = 'server.Server'
    mainModule = 'treasurehunt.main'
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
```

This is my first time using gradle, so I would be glad if you could explain in detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; the `Main-Class` attribute is "baked into" the jar. What you can do instead is to write a small launcher class with a `main` method that reads the command line and invokes `Server.main` or `Client.main`.